# Possibility to retract flag on comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging

I have noticed that even if I mistakenly flag a comment, I cannot be able to retract the flag afterward... I think it will be a good feature to add the possibility to retract flags on comments.

Comment: This feature-request  belongs in principle to the [mother meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as it is not specific to Phys.SE. Tip: Look out for duplicates.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will direct my request to the right place then.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285003/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [a duplicate question already exists in the appropriate place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285003/280545).